# Reading in standard input into a char array - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, iostream

I'm wondering what is the accepted way of getting input from the command line which captures white space as well.  I thought this would do it...

```
char text[500];   
int textSize = 0;

int main() {

    while (!cin.eof()) {
        cin >> text[textSize];
        textSize++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < textSize; i++) {
        cout << text[i];
    }

return 0;
}
```

But looks like it skips white space.  I switched to this...

```
char c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)  {
    text[textSize] = c;
    textSize++;
}
```

which works perfectly but I know this from a C programming book.  Wondering how I would handle it in c++

Comment: You could use `istream::get`

Comment: _`char text[500];`_ Rather use `std::string`.

Comment: [`while (!cin.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) is a mistake

Comment: I'll have a look at istream.  Thanks!  M.M, what do you mean by a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the stream extraction operator in C++ will skip whitespace. You can control this with the `noskipws` stream manipulator:

```
while (!cin.eof()) {
    cin >> noskipws >> text[textSize];
    textSize++;
}
```

That said, the program you've written has a pretty clear buffer overflow problem if you read too much text. If you're planning on reading a fixed number of bytes, use `istream::read`. If you'd like to read a variable number of bytes, consider using a `std::string` in conjunction with `istream::get`, like this:

```
std::string input;
char ch;

while (cin.get(ch)) {
    input += ch;
}
```

This doesn't have the risk of a buffer overflow and should handle as much text as possible (subject to restrictions on available memory, of course.)

Comment: Thanks!  When you say risk of buffer overflow - do you mean because if the input is larger than the array, the array will not have a proper termination.  I see also that you didn't actually have to provide an index to iterate when inserting into input "input += ch".  When I tried printing out, I thought I could iterate through it by doing input++ but that didn't work

Comment: @cpd1 Yes, more or less that's what he means. The exact answer to that is that you'll get undefined behaviour when you try to do that. See this for a detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why
 You can't do input++ because input is a string type, and the ++ operator isn't defined on strings.
What is defined on strings is the + operator, which simply appends the two strings, or in this case the string and the character.